# ReferenceError: session is not defined

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, session

I'm trying to get [Comment Tree](http://codecanyon.net/item/comment-tree/discussion/4779745) working on my site however when I run it I get the following error:

```
>**Error :** ReferenceError: session is not defined
>CommentTree.js?1.2
>Line 234
```

I've gone to the code and checked what is line 234:

```
if('moderate' in CommentTree.session && CommentTree.session.moderate == '1' && session.banned == '0' && comment.user.id != CommentTree.session.id && comment.user.banned == '0') 
    $('a.action.ban', $comment).show();
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong - I'm only writing the sessions in my PHP page:

```
$_SESSION['moderate']="1";
$_SESSION['banned']="0";
$_SESSION['id']=$user_data['xxx'];
```

If anyone could work out what is going on, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you get even a basic support when purchase a script?

Comment: @zerkms: especially when it seems to have bugs in it.

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy: imagined a customer who purchased a TV that doesn't work and asked a question on electrical engineers forum (instead of demanding a shop to replace it)

Comment: @zerkms: if he had support issues he should have emailed the author: http://codecanyon.net/user/Summoner#contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript code that you've got is missing the parent object on one of the checks:

```
session.banned == '0'
```

There is no variable named `session` defined, so that's why it is saying that *session is not defined*.  To fix this, simply change that to the following:

```
CommentTree.session.banned == '0'
```